# Calling set_style after set_range

Tags: c#, ms-word, styles, interop

I am trying to update a Word document programmatically.
I select a cell, then I update the text of its range and finally, I would like to call set_style on a particular section of this range. However, when doing so, the style applies to the whole range.

Here is a piece of code to demonstrate what I am currently doing:

```
Cell targetCell = _myWordDocument.Tables[1].Cell(i, 4);
targetCell.Range.Text = "Here is the text I will update later on";

//position before inserting the text 
int startFormat = targetCell.Start +12;  
//end position
int endFormat = targetCell.End - 23;
//new range    
Range formatMe = targetCell;             
formatMe.SetRange(startFormat, endFormat);
// this works just fine
formatMe.Bold = 1;                          
//this, however does not as it applies to the whole text
//not only the sub range I defined above
object style_name = "Heading 1"; // or Tag or whatever...
formatMe.set_Style(ref style_name);
```

Does anyone have any tip I could use?

Comment: There are two main types of Styles in Word, Paragraph and Character styles.  You are using a paragraph style and consequently it gets applied to the whole paragraph.  Try using a character style.  See here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/understanding-paragraph-character-list-and-table-styles-HA001187614.aspx